# prevent arm64 gcc from generating GOT entries for symbols that reside in other object files

Tags: c, assembly, elf, arm64

When compiling a **executable** on `x64`, gcc won't generate GOT entries for symbols that are present in other object files, e.g.:

```
// 1.c 
extern void (*const target)(char *c);
int main() {
    target("xxx");
}
// 2.c
void (*const target)(char *c) = 0;
```

Compliling with `gcc 1.c 2.c`, the call to `target` function is done by RIP-relative addressing.

But compiling the same code on arm64, turns out this call is proxied by a GOT entry, which require a relocation.

```
 7c0:   a9bf7bfd        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
 7c4:   910003fd        mov     x29, sp
 7c8:   90000080        adrp    x0, 10000 <__FRAME_END__+0xf5f8>
 7cc:   f947f800        ldr     x0, [x0, #4080]
 7d0:   f9400001        ldr     x1, [x0]
 7d4:   90000000        adrp    x0, 0 <_init-0x5e8>
 7d8:   9122a000        add     x0, x0, #0x8a8
 7dc:   d63f0020        blr     x1
```

If I move the defination of `target` into `1.c`, then the call to `target` is done by RIP-relative addressing, which is the same as x64.

How can I tell gcc on arm64 not to generate these unnecessary GOT entries?

---

My arm64 box is a virtual machine on Mac Apple M1

OS: `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`,  GCC: `gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0`. `gcc -v -c 1.c` shows:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch aarch64-linux-gnu 1.c -quiet -dumpbase 1.c -mlittle-endian -mabi=lp64 -auxbase 1 -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -o /tmp/ccyEpqZq.s
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (aarch64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/aarch64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (aarch64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 6a3864a8c3fe8bbb972fb5dbcb1f67d4
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 as -v -EL -mabi=lp64 -o 1.o /tmp/ccyEpqZq.s
GNU assembler version 2.34 (aarch64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/:/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
```

Comment: [The latest GCC produces PIEs which don't use the GOT even for ARM. You have to tell it to make a PIC to use the GOT](https://godbolt.org/z/3svaz9rGY). You may try with `-fno-pic` or `-fpie`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom  Thanks, GOT entries disappered with `-fno-pic`(`-fpie` seems not working). While `-fno-pic` works fine with the demo code in my post, but with my project, it raises the error `relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol 'mprotect@@GLIBC_2.17' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: @user2828102 Yes, PIC is required for shared libraries.

Comment: @fuz I'm not compiling a shared object, I'm compiling a PIE executable. And after I adding `-mcmodel=large` to resolve this `relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21` error, the GOT entries come back even I compiling with `-fno-pic`

Comment: @user2828102 I'm sorry, but I have no idea how the previous behaviour can be restored.  What is your reason for not wanting the new code generation?  The old PLT-based approach is actually slower than what gcc12 generates as the PLT stub just ends up doing indirection through the GOT anyway.

Comment: What OS and gcc version is this?  Can you include the output of `gcc -v -c 1.c`?

Comment: @NateEldredge Hi, I've attached these info to the main post, thanks!